# Google Chrome makes a new request if the URL isn't changing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

If I go to https://www.google.se/ in Google Chrome and then add a hash sign at the end like, https://www.google.se/# and hit enter in the address bar nothing happens but if I now once again hit enter without adding anything to the URL Chrome makes a new GET request and navigates to Google again.

If I do exactly the same in IE11 no new request is sent. I can hit enter as many times as I like. This is how I thought it worked in all browsers. The effect in Chrome causes me a small problem.

I guess it is the way Chrome has chosen to implement things and you have to live with that. Is there a way on the server side (ASP.NET MVC 4, C#) to determine if the request is such that the user just focused the address bar and hit enter or if the user actually made a real new GET request to the page (like having a blank address bar and typing in the URL for the first time)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developping a web app their is no way to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you are using ASP.NET it would be easiest to implement that functionality if you made a session variable when the user navigated to the page and saved the absolute path they navigated with.

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

This way you can check your logic against every further request from the same address and check if their url changed.